# Repeatedly traveling to the Were Glade for the 1/day 9 hour lycanthropy without a LA?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, planes

The Were Glade is a Planar Touchstone site described on page 164 of the Planar Handbook. The text of the book indicates that the higher-order-ability of the site allows you to transform into either a wolf or a wolf hybrid as a werewolf for up to 9 hours, with a limit of one transformation per day. This ability has a maximum charge of two uses and can be recharged by visiting the glade. Assuming a character has unrestricted access to the site, does this mean they can spend 9 hours each day transformed as a werewolf hybrid without gaining the additional HD and level adjustment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes

Revisiting the Glade to recharge the higher-order ability is part of how planar touchstone works (as well as the non-planar touchstones described in *Sandstorm*). Note that, as described on page 164 of the *Planar Handbook*, there is a 10% chance that there will be a fresh encounter waiting for the character when they return to the Were Glade (the book is not clear about what happens if they remain endlessly within the Glade, however). If they leave for a year or more, then when they return there is a guarateed encounter, as if they had never been there before.

Comment: Good catch. I only noticed the part about being absent for a year or more. Honestly, if someone were to set up shop there it would make sense that there would be a 10% chance every day of them being assailed by the creatures that would normally be found in the glade.